# Time stamping form form submits into MySQL

Tags: php, sql, forms, submit

I have got everything I need in terms of inputting my data into my data from a form but struggling to get it to timestamp or looking for the best methods.

submit form:

```
<form action="actions/newDocAdd.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="doc_title" id="doc_title" required="required" placeholder="Document Title"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="doc_content" id="doc_content" placeholder="Document Content"/><br/>
    <br><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Create Document" name="submit"/><br />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$hostname='localhost';
$username='******';
$password='******';

try {

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=******",$username,$password);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line

$sql = "INSERT INTO doc_list (doc_title, doc_content) VALUES ('".$_POST["doc_title"]."','".$_POST["doc_content"]."')";

if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
    header ('Location: ../docList.php');
}
else{
}

$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}

}
?>
```

I have a field inside the DB which is set to DATETIME named 'doc_create' but just need some idea at which point it timestamp the entry and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best point is default value for the field in table definition. you must define that field as follow:

```
timeStampField TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

also you can define field type as `DATETIME`
notice that this will work for mySql version MySQL 5.6.5 and higher.

Comment: I have defaulted the field as DATETIME however I need to add the timestamp when the record gets created from my form?

Comment: I made those changes and added NOW() and now works like a charm, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using NOW() when inserting the doc entry

```
<form action="actions/newDocAdd.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="doc_title" id="doc_title" required="required" placeholder="Document Title"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="doc_content" id="doc_content" placeholder="Document Content"/><br/>
    <br><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Create Document" name="submit"/><br />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$hostname='localhost';
$username='******';
$password='******';
$title = $_POST["doc_title"];
$content = $_POST["doc_content"];
try {

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=******",$username,$password);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO doc_list (doc_title, doc_content,doc_create) VALUES (:title, :content, NOW())");
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindParam(':content', $content);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    header ('Location: ../docList.php');
}
else{
... // your else code
}

$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```